# want to convert integer value to char format in java

Tags: java

I want to convert a double value into char format.
I have tried this:
double a=7.5;
char ch = a;  // ch should have 7.5

But it is giving error that double can't be converted to char

Comment: You can find lots of information about this topic here: https://www.google.ch/search?q=double+to+char&oq=double+to+char&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1686j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8#es_sm=91&espv=210&q=double+to+string++java

Comment: `char` holds 1 character. Do you by any chance meant `String` instead?

Comment: `char` is a single character. It can't have `7.5`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such character which appears as `7.5` You can create a String which contains the characters `7`, `.` and `5` i.e. three characters.

```
double d = 7.5;
String s = String.valueOf(d);
```

or

```
String s = "" + d;
```

Comment: And prefer `valueOf`.. where as  `""+` is a hack.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ You are not alone, but I prefer to be terse, unless performance matters in which case I don't use `String`

Answer (score 0):

The way you are trying to convert double to char is *not valid*. They both are different datatypes, so you have to ***type cast*** the one you want to convert.

**Prefered Method:**

```
double d1 = 65.5;
String temp = String.valueof(d1);
System.out.println(temp);
```

**Not so good method**

```
double d1 = 65.5;

char ch = (char) d1;

System.out.println(ch);
```

Comment: If i casting it like that it is converting it into character value like if d1 = 65 ch will have A

Comment: @user2903587 because there is **no** character with ascii value `65.5`.